# undefined method `foo_path' (I haven't called it)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I'm building a very simple rails app without resource routing.
I haven't called `trans_application_path` but view returned an error `` undefined method `trans_application_path' for ... ``

here's my code. any ideas?

**Controller**

```
# GET /trans/drafts
  def drafts_index
    @trans_drafts = TransApplication.where(applied: false)
  end

# GET /trans/apps
  def apps_index
    @trans_apps = TransApplication.where(applied: true)
  end
```

**View**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>drafts_index</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Applied</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @trans_drafts.each do |trans_draft| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= trans_draft.name %></td>
        <td><%= trans_draft.department %></td>
        <td><%= trans_draft.month %></td>
        <td><%= trans_draft.applied %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', trans_draft %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
```

**What I've done**

- generated Scaffold
- stop using resource routing and modified the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', trans_draft %></td>
```

There's you calling `trans_application_path`. `link_to` will use `polymorphic_path` for the url if you don't provide one. That will look at the class of the object it's given (`trans_draft`) and call the path helper for that class.

If you want the request to get to your controller you will need SOME route. If it's not the resource route (or equivalent), then pass the url you want into your `link_to` instead of the object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I should have mentioned one thing. I tried deleting the all lines that include "link_to" but the problem wasn't solved...

Comment: look at the backtrace of the error. It will tell you which line produced the error.

Comment: Sorry, as I restarted the server, the problem was solved. It seems to be due to cache...